# asp.net html page

Tags: asp.net

I have a (say) start.html page that I want to wrap up in an ASP.NET app, and be the first page to launch once deployed. How do I accomplish this within VS; not within IIS, but within VS to have a deployable package that will contain the start page information.

Answer (score 3):

It's really up to IIS to decide the order of priority. So you should define `start.html` as the first document in IIS. And if you cannot do this for various reasons and IIS decides to pick your default.aspx as default you will have to redirect to: `Response.Redirect("~/start.html")` but that would really be ugly stuff. Configure your web server appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `index.html`? I think it's the default.

Answer (score 0):

Naming the page `default.aspx` should do the trick.